# Check if a image exists with a given URL - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if an image exists given a url using javascript, but my code is not working. Thanks!

Here's my function :

```
function verifyImageURL(url, callBack) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.onload = function () {
        callBack(true);
  };
  img.onerror = function () {
        callBack(false);
  };
}
```

And Here's how I call it:

```
var url = "http://greenstyle.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Tucano-imagem-Silvia-Kochen-Wordpress.jpg";
verifyImageURL(url, function (imageExists) {
        if (imageExists === true) {
            alert("Image Exists");
        } else {
            alert("Image does not Exist");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Do you get any errors? Does it always return true or false?

Comment: What's not working? what happens? Are there any console errors? - try asking a question other than saying 'my code doesn't work'

Comment: This code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wLb9tka7/

Comment: I want to call another function that creates an image on a table, where i have the alert, and it doesn't go to my function

Comment: @sergiogomesdev please show us this code, your function does work. There must be a logic problem with the asynchronous call.

Comment: i want to return a the variable imageExists where i have the alerts, How can I return it and call it after?

Comment: create a global `imageExists` variable and do your callback like `function(exists){imageExists=exists}` or, if you've got multiple urls to check, modify your `verifyImageURL` so you can pass objects instead of string `verifyImageURL(imgToCheck){var img = new Image();
  img.src = imgToCheck.url; img.onload = function () {
        imgToCheck.exists = true;
  };
img.onerror = function () {
        imgToCheck.exists = false;
  }; var imgToCheck = {url:"http://something", exists: null}; verifyImageURL(imgToCheck);`

Comment: Then you should be able to determine if the check is being done (`imgToCheck.exists===null`) if it exists (`imgToCheck.exists`) or if it doesn't exists (`imgToCheck.exists===false`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open("get", url, true);x.onreadystatechange = function () { if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {alert('exist');}else{alert('does not exist'};}; x.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

This question hasn't had activity in a long time, but since I saw another recent answer, I thought I would share a solution which fits the asker's example pattern of using a callback, but alternatively returns a promise if no callback argument is provided:

> See [code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYSQYQQG0wIwQYwGsoBeKACk0RSQC4oc45MIEA7ASlID4oA3OAEskAbgBQYgGYBXNvmCC4bKFWQBJALYIA5tHLSATpnoBnYAcFttAGigKNEONOAB+em2kacEAx3oAFAzgNQRMIAB5GZlY2bnEZOQUlFWpNHT1DYygzCytbe0dnd09vA1t8LFwCQnp4ZFQMbDwiP34hUSlZeUVlVSQ03QpM03NLGygKpura6gbK5sJWgWF4rqTe1K1B8jEoKGHs0bzdu0EHJ2AAeQNGqqI3KA8vHygAH1hZ9Hnq6xOtEG8twWDzqNCBPzEXAA3icWMBTucio8Si93rIUJJLKhxHs4RNvkQZvUvlMiOIToJJBRQJA4FSChdruCiKQSGQAORPUrs6EnPYM5ykBGFK43AmEHF7KCU6ngRxU-6A8WsjkJbpKHn40nEMiKiDMiUnAC+JwgmDC0qp5Bp8uFjLF2pVUHZavWmsmdx1ducTPF5L2AHoA1AAALAEwAWggAA9IPIowYggYTvglGYoGAgiELWQPQs+VAXPs2BisUgC+4IAB3KCBYKhCJRFjsbjkAwQEzMPjQEi8ZZICh56pC9udzDdjgcf0TNPwpSYEAAJVklzkPagUKU+Ag9HM0ggRsleIKBjUA7IAAYjxB4UglOvJFgwtOZda5XTvfC2RyuT5NTCpWFU9z2yG8ABUzhFchyC4XsNwLPY7zYdc9wgSVAKHIhyEfc0ICnAsjXySCLnwvYTRTWdpQ0bQhWQmsBggGCX2ogA6ZAkAAUW7NhgBgUJgAgZCDHIdk+nZWwYJ4eDANfJC8KgdtgEMNh0ImZsDAgxFgGtSDgNIqU5KFVDVMwwhrQMfd9MIqB5yXFc13wilWPYrjBN4-jBJ8ESfCTcSKFg3gAKlWT7y4RTlJM9TNKgk8z30xD7yMiy0ILUzsKfPDJWs2zlzYVdt0cvYzm0FiTAMfAhUySVwoMZRM3rZ8xHIsQgygABVEx0igGMEA0MAWBMWgJFdHooAQEwQDkDjo16-qMiMEZcnGKhtDPRaxl5PZUzYdMBS-KAAGYIAOkQoFag6TAkXFNnSfQjCIrSOBY4AAAtBPIM50lBVApKCra02iFiVvIAADAASKEVrPI16HGyaKqrQRXs-WgQdsT7dG+pAOGNQqUnULZGMyJ7XvejGICx37UoBlggbgbRQYhqGkBhsaJrkVH0cJrGcbI-DyJG5JTOm2aWCGBbDiW2xmfWqxNpnHb4T2oUjpOs7gwuq6VBvCYcCFD7uc+egmxiAKFbHCA6YZ8HIfp6H6FMqBEeRvbOaor7Pn0voGLuzAHpFcocH0lM9bIA2PeJY2mGbTgpO2i2rcZ23VpZh3xTd8meaPG7dF9wP+YkPFMiFdkXuAYAwEGoNBFK4BqhY4rDBY1MNADMDowALw0ABxFiACswG0dlxDhqaZr6lg8+dABlS53d0HlxGF8e5qn9lZ-niBF4kYuOTLiuq4DSw+CwYQWJ6ieICPwn+8H4exFH-ARcvtfj9Pgdye35fRaJ+7nTfzAwhN7byAA) to view types and the overloaded function signature

```js
function loadImage (url, timeoutOrCallback, maybeCallback) {
  let timeout;
  let callback;

  if (typeof timeoutOrCallback === 'number') {
    timeout = timeoutOrCallback;
    if (typeof maybeCallback === 'function') callback = maybeCallback;
  }
  else if (typeof timeoutOrCallback === 'function') callback = timeoutOrCallback;

  const promise = callback
    ? undefined
    : new Promise(resolve => void (callback = resolve));

  const onlyRunOnce = {once: true};
  let timerId = 0;
  let done = false;

  if (typeof timeout === 'number') {
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      done = true;
      callback(false);
    }, timeout);
  }

  const img = new Image();

  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (done) return;
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    done = true;
    callback(true);
  }, onlyRunOnce);

  img.addEventListener('error', () => {
    if (done) return;
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    done = true;
    callback(false);
  }, onlyRunOnce);

  img.src = url;
  return promise;
}


// Usage examples:

function asyncExample (url, logId) {
  const timeout = 3e3; // 3s

  loadImage(url, timeout).then(imageLoaded => {
    console.log(`${logId}: async with timeout:`, imageLoaded)
  });

  loadImage(url).then(imageLoaded => {
    console.log(`${logId}: async:`, imageLoaded)
  });
}

function callbackExample (url, logId) {
  const timeout = 3e3; // 3s

  let cb = imageLoaded => console.log(`${logId}: callback with timeout:`, imageLoaded);
  loadImage(url, timeout, cb);
  
  cb = imageLoaded => console.log(`${logId}: callback:`, imageLoaded);
  loadImage(url, cb);
}

let url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxzmG.jpg';
asyncExample(url, 'SO image');
callbackExample(url, 'SO image');

url = 'https://invalid.example/image.jpg';
asyncExample(url, 'invalid image');
callbackExample(url, 'invalid image');
```